# If array has a specifc value

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I've been trying to create an array which will hold a set of numbers. In this case 10, 33, 55 and 99. What I'm looking for is something flexible to search the array for a variable to see if the number is in it.

```
var nrArray = [10, 33, 55, 99]; // Any number in this array will decide the function below

if ( 55 = nrArray ) {   // If the number 55 is in the array do the following
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "RUN1";
}
else  {             // If the number 55 does not exist in the array do the following
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "RUN2";
}

<p id="demo1">demo1</p>
<p id="demo2">demo2</p>
```

NOTE
55 in this example will be replaced with a variable that has a number set to it. And this number will vary

Comment: use if(nrArray.indexOf(55) > -1) ... ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: `indexOf()` method will help you

Comment: @trainoasis: `>= 0` or `> -1`.

Comment: Hi, could you please accept my answer if it's correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). `indexOf` method will return index of element if it's exist in array or -1 otherwise.

```
var nrArray = [10, 33, 55, 99];
var myVar = 55;

if (nrArray.indexOf(myVar) !== -1) {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "RUN1";
} else {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "RUN2";
}

<p id="demo1">demo1</p>
<p id="demo2">demo2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nrArray = [10, 33, 55, 99]; // Any number in this array will decide the function below

if (nrArray.indexOf(55) > -1 ) {   // If the number 55 is in the array do the following
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "RUN1";
}
else  {             // If the number 55 does not exist in the array do the following
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "RUN2";
}

<p id="demo1">demo1</p>
<p id="demo2">demo2</p>
```